# $A=BC$, $A,B$ are real symmetric $n\times n$ matrix, can we show $C$ is diagonalizable iff $A,B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra

$A=BC$, $A,B$ are real symmetric $n\times n$ matrix, can we show $C$ is diagonalizable iff $A,B$ are simultaneously  diagonalizable.

$C$ is diagonalizable if some invertible $P$ exists such that $P^{-1}CP$ is a diagonal matrix.

$A,B$ are simultaneously  diagonalizable, if some invertible $P$ exists such that $P^{-1}AP, P^{-1}BP$ are diagonal.

Whu...

Comment: $\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}\pmatrix{1&0\\ 1&1}=\pmatrix{2&-1\\ -1&1}\pmatrix{1&0\\ 1&0}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A = BC\;\Longrightarrow\;D_A = P^{-1}AP = (P^{-1}BP)(P^{-1}CP) = D_B(P^{-1}CP)$. Hence, if $B$ is invertible, then also $C$ is diagonalizable. Otherwise, nothing can be said.

Comment: Is there any examples? $C$ is diagonal, but $A,B$ can not be simutanenously diag?

Answer (score 1):

There's an instructive special case to consider:
Let $A$, $B$ be arbitrary real symmetric Positive Definite matrices. Then
$C = B^{-1}A$
$C$ is similar to $B^\frac{-1}{2}AB^\frac{-1}{2}A$ which is real symmetric PD, so $C$ is always diagonalizable.

But the choice of $A$ and $B^{-1}$ was arbitrary.  OP's conjecture then is that arbitrary real symmetric PD matrices always commute since that occurs *iff* they are simultaneously diagonalizable.  But that is obviously false.